# How do I right justify numbers with decimal points using Python 3.6

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to right justify the numbers in the output so all the decimal points line up, Using Python 3.6.1.

The general format I am using is:

```
print('Bonus: $',format(bonus, ',.2f'),sep='')
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the numbers to right justify and keep the currency format.  Here's a pic of output:

[image: Sales Output]

Comment: https://pyformat.info

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the numbers? Most simple methods will force you to establish max number of digits that the value can be. Eg. `str.rjust()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
print('{:<15}: {:>10.2f}'.format('Bonus', bonus),sep='')
```

The > takes care of right alignment while the .2f takes care of the decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining string formatters works:

```
>>> "Cash Money: %10s" % "$%.2f" % 6.124
'Cash Money:      $6.12'
```

The first one adds the symbol & formats the number, the second pads it to the proper length.

Used in a more realistic way:

```
str_bal = "$%.2f" % bal
print "Balance: %20s" % str_bal
```

A real world example:

I've build a report which intelligently resizes via mixing format strings:

```
format_string = "%-9s %-{}s %6.3f%% (%{}i/%{}i) total events: %{}i".format(
                 max_len_key, max_len_pos, max_len_total, max_len_events)
for entry in table:
    ...
    print format_string % (title, key, percent, pos, total, event)
```

which outputs:

```
Version:  1.0.0.0  2.688% (10/372) total events: 150
Version:  1.4.1.15 0.000% ( 0/181) total events:  73
```

Note: you can do this without mixing formatters, but I think this ends up clearer than the abomination `"%%-9s %%-%is %%6.3f%%%% (%%%ii/%%%ii) total events: %%%ii"` (which is the valid replacement for the first format string).